# Video classification with Keras

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, keras

I'm using Keras to classify video segments. My network architecture is a CNN followed by RNN, like the one presented in this paper: 
[Long-term Recurrent Convolutional Networks](http://jeffdonahue.com/lrcn/)
I'm using the TimeDistributed Layer Wrapper for the CNN part. Since my videos segments have a different sequence length, my `input_shape` is `(None, rows, cols, channels)`. The None is of course for the timesteps. This is my model:

```
seq_input = Input(shape=(None, 213, 213, 3 )
frame_sequence = TimeDistributed(cnn_model)(seq_input)
time_sequence = SimpleRNN(512, return_sequences=False)(frame_sequence)
predictions = Dense(nb_10, activation='softmax')(time_sequence)
```

For the training, I'm using fit_generator and a generator that yields batches of 32 sequences to train. My question is how to concatenate the sequences of data into a single batch, e.g:
`sequence_1` has the shape of `(5, 213, 213, 3)` i.e. 5 time steps
`sequence_2` has the shape of `(10, 213, 213, 3)` i.e. 10 time steps
If for example my batch size is 2, the generator should yield a batch with the shape `(2, None, 213, 213, 3)`.

How can I implement this in Keras ? Thanks

Comment: So - your videos have a varying length, am I right?

Comment: yes exactly, with a maximum length on 100 time steps

Comment: What is the approximate number of this videos?

Comment: Sorry I don't get the question. Do you mean the number of train samples ? It's about 6 million sequences

Comment: This is what I meant - OK. I would try to answer your question in a hour or two. Ok?

Comment: Yeah thnx, take your time. Just one last thing, I don't want to pad my sequence with a zero array to make all the sequences have the same length

Comment: It's beacuse of memory problems?

Comment: Basically because I think if the RNN has a `return_sequence=True` (which I do), the padding will be a problem in learning, i.e. a zero array must have a label now

Comment: You could use masking then. In this case - you simply don't care :)

Comment: Good idea, thanks !